# Why does lazy loading in dotnet core 5 add unnecessary elements to the response?

Tags: c#, reactjs, .net-core, next.js

I have a dotnet core web api that returns a list of candidates when I navigate to that endpoint. The candidate class has navigation properties that reference related data. I have also enabled Lazy Loading via the proxies package. The issue? I'm having is that the JSON response is a lot different from what I was expecting.

**This is the response I get:**

```
{
    "$id":"1",
    "$values":[
        {
            "$id":"2",
            "candidateId":2,
            "constituencyId":1,
            "constituency":{
                "$id":"3",
                "constituencyId":1,
                "name":"",
                "parish":"",
            },
            "member":{
                "$id":"4",
                "memberId":2,
                "prefix":"Mr",
                "firstName":"John",
                "middleName":"",
                "lastName":"Brown",
                "suffix":"",
                "partyId":2,
                "position":"",
                "joinDate":"1995-06-05T10:00:00"
            }
        },
        {
            "$id":"5",
            "candidateId":1,
            "constituencyId":2,
            "constituency":{
                ...
            },
            "member":{
                ...
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Why does it insert additional `$id` properties and a `$values` array? When I try to load the data into a Next.js table and display data from the nested objects, such as "member" and "constituency"; I get an error of undefined.

**The table accepts the data in the following format:**

```
<Table data={data.$values} >
```

I'm able to access top-level properties such as the "candidateId" with ease. However, if I try to access "position" within "member" I get an error that "member" is undefined.

```
<Table.Column prop={member.position}/> //member undefined
<Table.Column prop={constituency.name} /> //constituency undefined
```

Since the table takes the data and iterates over the objects in the `$values` array, I would assume that I should be able to directly access the properties in member or constituency

Even though I say the additional elements are unnecessary, I'm guessing that they are needed.

Comment: Please share a [mcve].

Comment: You likely have a circular reference in your model and have the serializer configured to preserve references. Doing so creates metadata (`$id`, `$values`, and `$ref`) in the JSON so that the reference can be properly serialized/deserialized. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-preserve-references?pivots=dotnet-5-0

Comment: @devNull You're right, after removing the line to preserve references, they were removed. However, it still doesn't allow me to access the nested objects. If I do `console.log(data[0].member.position)` it displays the value in the console but why would the `Table` not have access to member? Just for reference the `data` prop on `Table` generates a `data.map` behind the scenes and each `Table.Column` accesses the values of it.